# Pass make's used Makefile to submake

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile i have some targets, that call directly make:

```
all:                                                                                                                                   
        @$(MAKE) clean                                                                                       
        @$(MAKE) resources                                                                                                             
        @$(MAKE)
```

but this does not work, when passing custom makefile name to make - like

```
make -f MyMakefile
```

the -f option is not passed to sub-makes. How can I tell the main make to pass it to sub-makes?
For targets we have $(MAKECMDGOALS), it contains targets, passed to the main makefile
Is there something similar, which contains the name of the Makefile, used, passed with -f? like

```
make $(MAKEUSEDMAKEFILE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value of `MAKEFILE_LIST`:

```
THIS_MAKEFILE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

all:                                                                                                                                   
        @$(MAKE) -f $(THIS_MAKEFILE) clean                                                                                       
        @$(MAKE) -f $(THIS_MAKEFILE) resources                                                                                                             
        @$(MAKE) -f $(THIS_MAKEFILE)
```

Note that you must set `THIS_MAKEFILE` *before* you include any other makefiles, otherwise its value will be wrong.